# Javaws.exe missing from JRE 5.0

Tags: java, server

I'm currently building a SAN into my file server currently. In order to log in to set everything up it downloads a JNPL file. I understand to open this you need Java's `javaws.exe` program normally installed by default. But When I download the java versions that should have it, the .exe isn't there.

To specify the SAN requires `Java RE 5.0` or `6.0`, I am running a windows server 2012 R2 with an AMD processor.

I have tried:
`jdk-1_5_0_22-windows-amd64`
`jre-1_5_0_12-windows-amd64`
`jre-6u3-windows-amd64`
`Adoptium`
(As well as a few others that I forgot to document).

Comment: Java Web Start is [independently supported](https://openwebstart.com/) now

Comment: @g00se but unfortunately only for Java 8 or 11: FAQ [Which Java versions can be used to run my JNLP applications?](https://openwebstart.com/docs/FAQ.html#_which_java_versions_can_be_used_to_run_my_jnlp_applications) says: "Your JNLP applications can be run with either Java 8 and 11."

Comment: But why are you planning to run such an ancient JRE anyway?

Comment: where did you get your Java installer from?

Comment: Java Web Start for Windows x64 was only added to Java 6u12: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4802695, so you need at least that.

Comment: @PetrJaneček That was it. Didn't realize that they didn't add it to the x64's until 6u12. This fixed it!

Comment: [Java Web Start was distributed as part of the Java Platform until being removed in Java SE 11, following its deprecation in Java SE 9.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start) so the point is there's no future in standard JDK support. You need to use the independent version

Comment: @g00se, The solution was to download 6u12 x64 AMD supported.

Comment: *That* version (which more than likely has vulns btw) might support it but you can't move forward. Support has ceased in standard Java